# Use Stripe Webhook to get the updated data and update the database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm new to stripe webhooks. My application runs with user subsctipns. I got the user successfully use strie to activate their subscription plan monthly. now all i want is when ever stripe chargers the user with a monthly subscription, I want to update my database with the next payment date.

Ex: If user was charged on 27th July and the next payment date would be 27th Aug, I want to update my database with the customer's next payment date and send the user the notification regarding the same, as. you have been charged by your monthly subscription o plan(on 27th July) and your next payment date would next month(27 Aug).

I have an idea of how can i send user notifications but the problem I'm facing is the stripe is not updated by the database. I have used webhooks to get the notifications and update method but am unable to do so.

If anyone could guide me with this,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be notified when customers pay an invoice, you can listen to the webhook event [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded). In the payload you will get an invoice object, which has a [`subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription) property.

If you retrieve that subscription, then you can find the [`current_period_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_end) property to know when the next invoice will be created.